# Fill previous row of a list automatically

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of items with its transaction details. Columns contain date, item name, buy qty, buy rate, sell qty, sell rate etc.

I have added a column indicating the row in which this item has appeared earlier in the list. If item name is in column B, I can fill the formula

```
=IFNA(MAX(FILTER(ROW(B:B),A:A<INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),1)),B:B=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2)))),0)
```

which returns the row number where the current item has appeared. If the item is currently appearing the first time, the function returns 0. That works fine.

I would like to fill the entire column with the formula so that it fills when new row is added or updates when an item name is changed. How can I achieve it?

I tried QUERY to generate the entire column, but could not get the result. What is in my mind is something like

```
=FILTER(<function>,B:B<>"")
```

Can you suggest any methods?

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(A:A="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 B:B&COUNTIFS(B:B, B:B, ROW(B:B), "<="&ROW(B:B))-1, {
 B:B&COUNTIFS(B:B, B:B, ROW(B:B), "<="&ROW(B:B)), ROW(B:B)}, 2, 0), 0)))
```

[image]

or:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(IF(COUNTIFS(B:B, B:B, ROW(B:B), "<="&ROW(B:B))=1, 0, 
 VLOOKUP(B:B, {B:B, ROW(B:B)}, 2, 0))))
```

[image]